# Kinetic Energy of a Block-Bullet System

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy

A bullet of mass $m$ is fired towards a wooden block of mass $M$. At a particular instant of time when the bullet is inside the block, the speed of the block is $V$ and the speed of the bullet, relative to the block, is $v$. I would like to find the total kinetic energy of the system at this point.

Considering the bullet and block as separate entities, it should be $$\frac 12 MV^2 +\frac 12 m(v+V)^2$$

But I could also look at the bullet and block as one body with velocity $V$, and then add the extra velocity of the bullet which has not been accounted for: $$\frac 12 (M+m)V^2 +\frac 12 m v^2 $$

Which one of these is correct?

Comment: Kinetic energy is reference frame dependent. Do you want a lab-based value or the center-of-mass based value? How did you arrive at each of these calculations? What is your thinking for each?

Comment: Top is correct. Bottom would also be correct for momentum, but because energy goes like velocity squared, you can’t decompose velocity into parts and sum the energy from each.

Comment: @BillN I want the energy with respect to the ground, say. What are lab/ center if mass -based values? Again, for the first expression I thought that the block moves with speed $V$ and the bullet with speed $v+V$ and then added their individual energies. For the second expression, I thought of the bullet and the block as one entity with speed $V$, and then added the extra energy of the bullet.

Comment: Is this collision elastic or inelastic?

Comment: @Gert I don’t know how this can even be seen as a collision. The block offers a constant resistance $R$ to the motion of the bullet, if that helps.

Comment: Since as they touch at some point it's a collision.

Comment: @Gert Maybe, but I don’t know how to answer your question.

Comment: The collision is elastic if *kinetic energy is conserved*.

Comment: @Gert Yes, I know. I believe it isn’t conserved in a real-life situation due to emission of sound etc.

Comment: @Tavish Correct: such collisions are always inelastic. That's why I was asking because your question and the answer to it, both assume CoKE.

Comment: @Gert Why is that relevant anyway? The question only concerns an instant of time.

Comment: It's HIGHLY relevant. You're assuming the irreversible losses are very small. But that's just an assumption. In real life the losses are significant. I.o.w. it's not a well defined problem.

Comment: @Gert Where did I assume anything about the losses? Why is it not well-defined?

Comment: Because block-bullet systems in real life are about inelastic collisions. You 'force' KE to be conserved. That's **OK of course** but it makes it a 'thought experiment'. More realistic would be a cue ball hitting a pool ball: collisions like that are near-100% elastic.

Comment: @Gert Still don’t see how it is relevant to the question. It is solely a conceptual question on calculating kinetic energies, not whether they are conserved or not.

Comment: Oh, so you're calculating KEs but aren't interested in whether KE is conserved or not?? I think we're done here.  Have a nice day now.

Comment: @Gert Exactly. ${}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kinetic energy of system depends on the choice of reference frame.  To compare the energy of different objects or use conservation of energy, each energy must be defined in the same reference frame.

The most common choice would be to define a "lab frame."  This is your reference frame, standing at rest next to the experiment happening.  In this case all velocities used in the kinetic energy equations should be measured relative to you.

The total kinetic energy is the sum of the individual energy of each particle
$$ K = \frac{1}{2}MV^2 + \frac{1}{2}mu^2,$$
where $V$ is the speed of the block relative to you and $u$ is the speed of the bullet relative to you.

Instead of knowing the bullet's speed relative to you directly, you know the bullet's speed relative to the block.  We can rewrite the bullet's speed relative to you in terms of the variables you care about
$$u = v + V.$$

Putting it all together, the correct way to account for the kinetic energy of the system would be
$$K = \frac{1}{2}MV^2 + \frac{1}{2}m(v+V)^2$$

Comment: Can you explain why the second expression is incorrect? Is it because I can’t take the bullet and the block as ‘one’ particle?

Comment: @Paul T. has explained it perfectly, I think. Other comments have also pointed out that kinetic energy is frame-dependent. If you want a further step of "expliciteness", it's because the speed V and the speed v are relative to different frames --V with respect to you, and v with respect to the block. And you shouldn't mix those in dynamical problems. Good question, though, as it clarifies possible pitfalls.

Comment: If two particles have identical motion than we can group them together.  If the bullet also had speed $V$, we could rearrange the first equation in the answer to be one term with the total mass $(m+M)$.  But the bullet does not have the same speed as the block.

Comment: Alright, I think I get it.